# Singelshot from multiple Kinects / synchronize Kinects

Tags: ros, usb, syncronization, pandaboard, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm trying to build a portable device with a pandaboard and two kinects on it. Because of the fact that the Pandaboard just provide one USB-bus I would like to knows if it's possible to synchronize the sensors in a way that they are interlacing (pictures are alternating) or if I could trigger the Sensor to take a picture ( for the first and then for the second sensor with minimal latency).
I just need singleshots (but from both sensors at the same time) after pressing a button, respectively not the full videostream is needed. Is there a way to do that with just one USB-bus?

EDIT: Due to the fact that I'm using an ARM Platform (Pandaboard ES) my computational resources are very limited I will probably use two boards and synchronize the boards system-time with crony. Afterwards I would be able to use [message_filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters) as Mac mentioned it. Unfortunately is my publishing rate pretty bad (1-2 pointclouds per second) so I doubt that this will give me sufficient solution. Is there a way to converge the publishing time of the sensors?

I would be glad about any idea or recommendations.
Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35296/singelshot-from-multiple-kinects-/-synchronize-kinects/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far as I know, doing this with a single USB bus is impossible; one Kinect will completely saturate the bus that it's on.

Also, there isn't (as far as I know), any concept of "triggering" a Kinect. What you'll need to do is set up a node that listens to both Kinects and implements a synchronization routine (see the approximate synchronization stuff in [message_filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters)). This node would also publish a service that your trigger calls, and then saves the most-recent synchronized pair of images to disk, or wherever else you want to put them.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1